# How to join collection where foreign field is an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working with mongodb and need help to join collections where the foreign field is a value in an array.

Collection 1:

### (Properties)

```
> db.properties.findOne({'agentid':'mike@gmail.com'},{'agentid':1,'contact':1})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d2cc296f07d417008b4567"),
        "agentid" : "mike@gmail.com",
        "contact" : [
                {
                        "type" : "listingAgent",
                        "id" : "1",
                        "name" : "Mike",
                        "telephoneType" : "",
                        "telephone" : "",
                        "email" : "mike@gmail.com"
                }
        ]
}
```

collection 2:

### (agents)

```
> db.agents.findOne({'email':'mike@gmail.com'})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5979d1400045fecc0800004c"),
        "id" : "35",
        "agentID" : "mike@gmail.com",
        "email" : "mike@gmail.com",
        "name" : "Mike",
        "telephone" : "",
        "status" : true
}
```

collection 3:

### (users)

```
> db.users.findOne({'email':'mike@gmail.com'})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5979d0e20045feac0d00003f"),
        "id" : "20",
        "email" : "mike@gmail.com",
        "type" : "publisher",
        "status" : "inactive",


}
```

Now as per above collections I need to aggregate users and need to join 'users' collection with 'agents' and 'properties'.

The issue is that the collection 'properties' is having foreign field 'email' as a value in an array so i am not able to apply lookup on it.

I need to join these collections with field 'email' but due to having foreign field 'email' as a value in an array in 'properties' collections I am not getting results.

i am hereby showing my attempt as below

```
$query =
array( 
array('$lookup'=>array(
           'from'=>'agents`',
           'localField'=>'email',
           'foreignField'=>'email',
           'as'=>'users_agents'
           )
   ),

array('$unwind'=>'$properties.contact'), 

 array('$lookup'=>array(
            'from'=>'properties',
            'localField'=>'email',
            'foreignField'=>'contact.email',
            'as'=>'users_properties'
            )
   ),


array('$match'=>array(
'$and'=>array(array('users_properties.offline'=>false),
array('users_agents.status'=>true)))),


 array('$project'=>array(
            '_id'=>1,
            'id'=>1,
            'username'=>1,
            'firstname'=>1,
            'lastname'=>1,
            'email'=>1,
            'type'=>1,
            'status'=>1,
          )
 ), 

);

$collection_users->aggregate ($query );
```

Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: Please try actually showing the documents as they appear stored in MongoDB. Please use the `mongo` shell and past the text ( not images ) of the actual data you expect to join. At a brief glance, what you are calling an "array" would not appear to actually be an array. But showing actual documents would make this clear.

Comment: Yes, please show sample documents and provide sample result which you are trying to get

Comment: i had edited my post as per your request and added actual documents so please kindly refer it and please help me. Thanks

Comment: So what is the expected join actually supposed to be? Is it properties to agents or properties to users, or what exactly? Joining on a field in the array is not really an issue. You probably really want to start with properties as the initial source, but you don't really give a clear explanation of what the query is meant to do. Might also help if you showed what you have tried, as that should give some indication of your intent, even if it does not presently work for you.

Comment: i need to join users with properties and agents both using field 'email'. Aggregate function will be on users and i need to check the status in agents collection and need to check published properties from properties collection. The collections are having other fields also, in question i am displaying only the sample fields which need to be used while joining.

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari See the `@` there. That's how you address your comments to the person who asked. I'm asking you to show your "attempt" because I want to see what conditions you expect to "filter" on determine from the the order of importance on how each `$lookup` should be represented. MongoDB has no restriction on joining content that is in an array, so it will only be a syntax problem in your attempt. So we need to see your "attempt" in order to clearly see what the actual problem is.

Comment: @NeilLunn  
i am sorry for my mistake, i had updated my question and added my attempt, i hope this will be fine. thanks a lot for your efforts, please refer the question again with my attempted query

Comment: @NeilLunn please check my updated question with my attempted query and please help me to fix this issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ Irshad Ahmed Ansari Have you got the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Properties.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$contact"
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Users",
        localField: "contact.email",
        foreignField: "email",
        as: "user"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "agents",
        localField: "contact.email",
        foreignField: "email",
        as: "agent"
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your effort but i request you to check my collections, my attempted query and my question again, i need to aggregate users not properties, and i need to join users collection which is having an contact so my foreign field can be "contact.email" not my local field. Still i tried your way and it is not working. Please kindly check my question again and please kindly help me out.